# Oauth2 authentification with Angular 4

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I would like to use the authentification oauth2 of Google/Facebook in an angular 4 application.

I don't want to use the famous service Firebase or Oauth0.

Do you know some nice libraries to implement an authentification with google or facebook?

Thank you